# Flutter: ShowDialog not working with the OnTap() method of a ListTile

Tags: flutter, dart, showdialog

I am using a drawer to create a menu that houses ListTiles for the options. I want to create a popup when the tiles are tapped by the user. Currently, the code displays nothing when the tiles are tapped even though after the showDialog there is a Navigator.pop().

```
// Drawer that includes the ListTiles in question
 Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Text('Smash Tracker'),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text(
                    'About',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Smash',
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(77, 114, 152, 1.0),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  // Show PopUp
                  showDialog(context: context, child:
                    new AlertDialog(
                      title: new Text(
                        'About',
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Smash"),
                      ),
                      content: new Text(
                        'This is a placeholder. This is a placeholder. This is a placeholder. This is a placeholder.',
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Smash"),
                      ),
                    )
                  );

                  // Doesn't run
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
```

Here is a demo:

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/fAWLHOS41nqSNvyc9f)

The other ListTiles have the  only have Navigator.pop() inside of their onTap() method.

Comment: Why are you using `Navigator.pop()` after `showdialog`?

Comment: It was used in answer to a question I thought was similar to my issue.

Comment: First do `Navigator.pop()` to close the drawer and then call `showDialog`

Comment: I moved the ```Navigator.pop()```  above the ```showDialog``` and it only closes the drawer with no pop up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dialog isn't showing because you are popping it immediately with the `Navigator.pop(context)`. You can `await` the `Dialog` since it returns a `Future<T>` before popping.

I added a demo using your widget tree as an example:

```
Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Smash Tracker'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'About',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Smash',
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(77, 114, 152, 1.0),
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () async { // mark the function as async
                print('tap');
                // Show PopUp

                // await the dialog
                 await showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    child: new AlertDialog(
                      title: new Text(
                        'About',
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Smash"),
                      ),
                      content: new Text(
                        'This is a placeholder. This is a placeholder. This is a placeholder. This is a placeholder.',
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Smash"),
                      ),
                    ));

                // Doesn't run
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

OUTPUT:

[image]